# angular 2 - lazy loader directive can not read property update of underfined

Tags: angular

My code

```
import { CameraService, CameraDestinationType, CameraPictureSourceType } from 'angular-cordova/plugin/camera'
import { LazyloadDirective } from 'achromatic/lazyload'
@Component({
    template: `
            <div *ngIf="selected">
                <div [lazyload] width="100" height="100"></div>
            </div>

    `,
    providers: [createDiscussionService, CameraService]
})
export class CreateDiscussionComponent  {
    @ViewChild(LazyloadDirective) lazyloadDirective: LazyloadDirective;
    selected: any = false
    uploadImage(): void {
        this.cameraService.getPicture({...})
        .subscribe(data_url => {
            if (data_url) {this.selected = true}
            this.lazyloadDirective.update(data_url)
        })
    }
}
```

What it does is, When user selects a photo, It show div wrapper and then load the photo data into the lazyload div

problem: after user clicked the photo, I got this error

`Cannot read property 'update' of undefined`

Interestingly, If I remove the `<div *ngIf="selected">` everything works just fine. I suspect the condition might have something to do with the lazyload not being able to update

Comment: Where do you call `uploadImage()`? `lazyloadDirective` won't be available before `ngAfterViewInit()`

Comment: I call when user click the browse photo button

Comment: updated the question a bit for more detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `selected` is `false` this part

```
       <div *ngIf="selected">
            <div [lazyload] width="100" height="100"></div>
       </div>
```

won't exist in the DOM and therefore also no `LazyloadDirective` directive instance.

Perhaps you want to use `hidden` instead

```
       <div [hidden]="!selected">
            <div [lazyload] width="100" height="100"></div>
       </div>
```

or `@ViewChildren()`, which updates when `selected` changes between `true` and `false`.